# Socket.io production enviroment

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, cors, next.js13

`` Acess to XMLHttpRequest at <BACKEND_URL_HERE> from origin 'https://aroid.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. ``

I have hosted the backend in [Railway](https://railway.app/) and frontend in Vercel

This is the Backend code

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const {Server} = require('socket.io')
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors : {
        origin : "*"
    }
})
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`User Connected : ${socket.id}`);
    socket.on("send_message", (data) => {
        console.log("Data : ", data)
        socket.broadcast.emit("recive_message", data)
    })
})

server.listen(3001, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is running...");
})
```

Frontend code in next.js this is a simple chat app while i was learning about Socket.io

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io.connect(<BACKEND_URL>);

export default function Home() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [allMessages, setAllMessages] = useState([]);

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    socket.emit("send_message", { message, user: "user1", time : formatAMPM(new Date) });
    let data = { message, user: "user1" , time : formatAMPM(new Date)};
    setAllMessages([...allMessages, data]);
    setMessage("");
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("recive_message", (data) => {
      data.user = "user2";
      setAllMessages([...allMessages, data]);
    });
  }, [socket, allMessages]);

return (<> Element </>)
}
```

Why the error is occuring in production evviroment even after linking the frontend and backend I can't find it out

Tried this thing for the cors error

```js
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors : {
        origin : <FRONTEND_URL>,
        methods : ["GET", "POST"],
    }
})
```